# C# MySQL database restore

Tags: c#, mysql, database, process, streamreader

I am trying to restore MySQL database data from a dump file, using C# codes.

I am suppose to execute the following command:
mysql --verbose --user=root --password=qwerty123456 test < C:\Users\Default\testing.SQL

I know that C# doesn't recognise the "<" symbol so I tried several ways but it still did not work. Can anybody help me with this? I want to restore all my database data back into MySQL using C# codes.

Thanks in advance.

```
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysql.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"--verbose --user=root --password=qwerty123456 test";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.Start();

            StreamReader sr = process.StandardOutput;
            sr = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\Default\testing.SQL");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<` handling should (IIRC) be OK if you simply set `UseShellExecute = true`.

However, if you really want to avoid the shell exec, `<` is an *input* - you should be writing the file to `StandardInput`. I'l probably leave `StandardOutput` alone (set `RedirectStandardOutput = false` if you don't actively want the output).

Untested, but maybe:

```
        using(var stdin = process.StandardInput)
        using(var reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\Default\testing.SQL")) {
            string line;
            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
                stdin.WriteLine(line);
            }
            stdin.Close();
        }
```

(which should pipe in the file line by line)